# Chilkat C# Crypt2 vs .NET framework encryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, chilkat

anyone out there who has used [Chilkat C# Crypt2 library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csCrypt2Ref.html)? How does it compare with the .NET framework encryption library? Any pros/cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd kill for [`public string CryptAlgorithm {get; set; }`](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csCrypt2Doc.html#prop004) ([here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csCrypt2Ref.html)) because of

> Selects the encryption algorithm for encrypting and decrypting. Possible values are: "pki", "aes", "rijndael", "blowfish", "blowfish2", "des", "3des", "rc2", "arc4", "twofish", "pbes1" and "pbes2".

Personally, I'm more than sure that this is a god-like-object (which includes compression, encryption, encoding).

Comment: Your god-like object includes both "aes", "rijndael" as algorithms. Also  believes "pki, "pbes1" and "pbes2"are algorithms. You know what God says, "gotta have faith!"